# How to Animate Div from Bottom of the Screen

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div that opens from the right.  Currently it literally starts from the top of the page and "moves" to the bottom.  I would like to animate it from the bottom right, not from the top to the bottom.

Here is my css:

```
.helper {
width: 0px;
position: fixed;
bottom: 60px;
right: -10px;
background-color: #E3E7EA;
overflow-x: auto;
overflow-y: scroll;
transition: 0.5s;
padding-left: 10px;
z-index: 1000;
transition: all 0.4s ease 0s;
```

}

Here is my javascript:

```
function openHelper() {
var myBoxWidth = $("#myHelper").width();
if (myBoxWidth > 0) {
    document.getElementById("myHelper").style.width = "0px";
    document.getElementById("myHelper").style.right = '-10';
}
else {
    document.getElementById("myHelper").style.width = "520px";
    document.getElementById("myHelper").style.right = '0';
}
```

}
function closeHelper() {
document.getElementById("myHelper").style.width = "0px";
document.getElementById("myHelper").style.right = '-10';
}

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="myHelper" class="helper">
<span><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeHelper()">X</a></span>
<div>
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>
```

Click

Here is a fiddle demonstrating my issue [My Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/queenbee61/um5pghk0/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply Change the height to a fixed height in the css:

```css
.helper {
    width: 0px;
    height: 300px;
    etc
}
```

That's it! Here is a JSFiddle for the same: https://jsfiddle.net/dbrsgevf/3/

UPD:
An alternative is to use max-height.

```
.helper {
    width: 0px;
    max-height: 200px;
    etc
}
```

A JSFiddle for the same: https://jsfiddle.net/9o2g4e5x/

Another Alternative is constraining the size with max-height, and using javascript to edit those constraints. This gives it a grow effect:

JS:

```js
function openHelper() {
    var myBoxWidth = $("#myHelper").width();
    if (myBoxWidth > 0) {
        document.getElementById("myHelper").style.width = "0px";
        document.getElementById("myHelper").style.right = '-10';
        document.getElementById("myHelper").style.maxHeight = "0px";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("myHelper").style.width = "520px";
        document.getElementById("myHelper").style.right = '0';
        document.getElementById("myHelper").style.maxHeight = "190px";
    }
}
function closeHelper() {
    document.getElementById("myHelper").style.width = "0px";
    document.getElementById("myHelper").style.right = '-10';
    document.getElementById("myHelper").style.maxHeight = "0px";
}
```

CSS:

```
.helper {
    width: 0px;
    max-height: 0px;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9o2g4e5x/2/

Comment: Thanks, but I can't put a "specific" height on it because content is actually dynamic.  Your sample opens and closes it from the right, but it does not collapse and expand it from the bottom like I want it to work.

Comment: You can use max-height instead. Do you want it to grow from the bottom right or just pop out from the right?

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: No Problem! Hope it helped!